# Android Studio builds doesn't care about my Gradle flavors?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I'm trying to use flavors to build different APKs with different asset qualities. The problem is, that after selecting a build variant, it still seems to run all the flavors, rather than just the correct on.

So my `build.gradle` looks like this.

```
task initialize{
     doLast {            
         configureObbFile.execute()
         setupScreenSupport.execute()
     }
} 

android {

  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
      println("Flavor: default")
      applicationId com.test.package
      minSdkVersion 19
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionName "1.0.0"
  }

  flavorDimensions "AssetSize"
  productFlavors {
      tiny {
          println("Flavor: tiny assests")
          pak_name_suffix = "tiny"
          initialize.execute()
      }
      small {
          println("Flavor: small assests")
          pak_name_suffix = "small"
          initialize.execute()
      }
      normal {
          println("Flavor: normal assests")
          pak_name_suffix = "normal"
          initialize.execute()
      }
      tablet {
          println("Flavor: tablet assests")
          pak_name_suffix = "tablet"
          initialize.execute()
      }
      hightable {
          println("Flavor: hightable assests")
          pak_name_suffix = "hightable"
          initialize.execute()
      }
  }
  [...]
}
```

I get build output something like this

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleHightableDebug]

> Task :app:configureObbFile

> Task :app:setupScreenSupport
Screens pak_name_suffix = "tiny"

> Task :app:initialize
> Task :app:initialize
> Task :app:initialize
> Task :app:initialize
> Task :app:initialize

> Configure project :app
Flavor: default
Flavor: tiny assests
Flavor: small assests
Flavor: normal assests
Flavor: tablet assests
Flavor: hightable assests
```

As you can see, it **does** start with **app:assembleHightableDebug**, but then it just performs all the flavors starting from top to bottom. I'd like it to only do the HighTable partition (and default). What's wrong? What am I doing wrong? Weird thing is that it only seem to run **configureObbFile** and **setupScreenSupport** once, with **'tiny'** flavor.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove every `initialize.execute()` line from your flavors. And take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to know how to properly decline your app with flavors.

Comment: Does not answer the question. What is improper about my flavor setup? The link provided no insight on that.